# Rotated Conic Section without $x$ and $y$

Tags: analytic-geometry

I'm looking for a proof of this following theorem :

Given $ax^2+bxy+cy^2=k$, to standardize equation of this conic section with coefficient of $x'$ being $a'$ and coefficient of $y'$ being $b'$, then $a'$ and $b'$ are the solutions to this equation:

$$m^2-(a+c)m+\left( ac-\frac{b^2}{4} \right) = 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R(\theta)=
\begin{pmatrix}
   \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\
  -\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}$ such that $
\begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix}=R(\theta)
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$.

\begin{align*}
  ax^2+bxy+cy^2 &=
  \begin{pmatrix} x & y \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
   a & \frac{b}{2} \\
   \frac{b}{2} & c
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix}
   a' & 0 \\
   0 & b'
\end{pmatrix}
&=R(\theta)^T
\begin{pmatrix}
   a & \frac{b}{2} \\
   \frac{b}{2} & c
\end{pmatrix}
R(\theta) \\ &=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{a+c}{2}+\frac{a-c}{2}\cos 2\theta-\frac{b}{2} \sin 2\theta &
  \frac{b}{2}\cos 2\theta+\frac{a-c}{2}\sin 2\theta \\
  \frac{b}{2}\cos 2\theta+\frac{a-c}{2}\sin 2\theta &
  \frac{a+c}{2}+\frac{c-a}{2}\cos 2\theta+\frac{b}{2} \sin 2\theta
\end{pmatrix} \\
\end{align*}

Now
\begin{align*}
  \tan 2\theta &= \frac{b}{c-a} \\
  a'+b' &= a+c \\
  a'b' &=
  \left( \frac{a+c}{2} \right)^2-
  \left( \frac{c-a}{2}\cos 2\theta+\frac{b}{2}\sin 2\theta \right)^2 \\
  &= \left( \frac{a+c}{2} \right)^2-
  \left(
    \frac{b}{2\tan 2\theta}\cos 2\theta+\frac{b}{2}\sin 2\theta
  \right)^2 \\
  &= \left( \frac{a+c}{2} \right)^2-
     \frac{b^2}{4\sin^2 2\theta} \\
  &= \left( \frac{a+c}{2} \right)^2-
     \frac{b^2(1+\tan^2 2\theta)}{4\tan^2 2\theta} \\
  &= \left( \frac{a+c}{2} \right)^2-
     \frac{(c-a)^2+b^2}{4} \\
  &= ac-\frac{b^2}{4}
\end{align*}

> **Note briefly**
>
> $a'$ and $b'$ are the eigenvalues of $
> \begin{pmatrix}
>    a & \frac{b}{2} \\
>    \frac{b}{2} & c
> \end{pmatrix}$, that is
>   $$\det
> \begin{pmatrix}
>    a-m & \frac{b}{2} \\
>    \frac{b}{2} & c-m
> \end{pmatrix}
> =0$$